# How is the difference between “to cite” and “to quote” made clear in German?

Tags: meaning, difference, single-word-request

In English, there’s a difference between the verbs [to cite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cite) and [to quote](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quote) (both links refer to Merriam-Webster).

The website [differencebetween](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/words-language/difference-between-cite-and-quote/) states (and I quote):

> **Cite vs Quote**
>
> The English words “cite” and “quote” are very similar and are used by people, sometimes, without knowing the differences between them.
>   They cannot be interchanged or confused with each other.
>   “Quoting” is basically repeating something someone has said or written verbatim, and “citing” means giving reference to a particular subject or words or thought by some person who is proficient to prove a point or theory or thought.
>   […]
>   “Quoting” refers to reproducing the words of another person verbatim;
>   “citing” refers to giving an example of some subject for substantiating oneself.

Google Translate offers *zitieren* for both *to cite* and *to quote*, and Leo lists *zitieren* and *anführen* (among other meanings) for both.

If I want to be precise and retain the meaning of *quote* or *cite*, how should the following sentences be worded in German?

> 1. The judge cited a number of laws to prove his point.
> 2. The student quoted Shakespeare in his presentation.

Comment: @userunknown Es geht hier nicht darum, dass der Unterschied zwischen _to cite_ und _to quote_ erklärt werden soll, sondern darum eine deutsche Entsprechung für diesen Unterschied zu finden, da _zitieren_ im Deutschen beide verschiedenen Bedeutungen abdeckt. Es ist also durchaus eine Frage zur deutschen Sprache, die auch völlig ohne den Verweis auf _to cite_ und _to quote_ gestellt werden könnte, die hier nur als Beispiele fungieren.

Comment: @userunknown Ja, danke für den Tipp, das hatte ich tatsächlich nicht getan. Dann könntest du nach dem Edit ja deinen Kommentar löschen. Dann lösche ich natürlich auch meinen ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in assuming that the two meanings of *cite* and *quote* are often merged (and mixed up) in the one German word *zitieren*, much like the two English words are sometimes imprecisely interchanged.

The German term for using someone else’s words verbatim (word for word), i.e. the English *quote*, is *zitieren* (meaning 1 in the [Duden entry](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zitieren)).

In the following two sentences, *zitieren* means that a passage of text is quoted without alteration:

> 1. Ich *zitiere* [wortwörtlich] den Bericht der letzten Vollversammlung.
> 2. Um Goethe zu *zitieren*, „sag’s ihm, er kann mich im Arsche lecken!“

There are other ways to say this, depending on context.
For example, in our second sentence, you could also use *bemühen* ironically:

> Um Goethe zu *bemühen*, „sag’s ihm, er kann mich im Arsche lecken!“

The English verb *to cite* is a bit more difficult, because it may mean *to quote*, but it can also mean to just *refer to* something without actually quoting it.
The German words *anführen* and *verweisen* correspond very well to this:
They tell us that some text, opinion etc. is used. That actual piece of text may or may not be quoted (meaning 2 in the Duden entry of [anführen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anfuehren); meaning 2 and 3 in the entry of [verweisen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verweisen)):

> **anführen**
>   2a. vorbringen, erwähnen, aufzählen
>   2b. benennen
>   2c. zitieren, wörtlich wiedergeben
>
> **verweisen**
>   2. auf etwas hinweisen, aufmerksam machen
>   3a. veranlassen, sich an eine bestimmte andere Person oder Stelle zu wenden
>   3b. (Rechtssprache) übergeben, überweisen

To sum it up:
If you quote something verbatim, always use the original wording, and call it *zitieren* / *Zitat*.
If you cite something without quoting its words, like a reference to another work in your term paper, call it *verweisen* / *Verweis*.

And finally, using the examples from the question:

> 1. The judge cited a number of laws to prove his point.
>      Der Richter *führte* eine Reihe von Gesetzen *an*, um seinen Standpunkt zu belegen.
>      Or: Der Richter *verwies* auf eine Reihe von Gesetzen, …
>      [He may or may not have additionally quoted them.]
> 2. The student *quoted* Shakespeare in his presentation.
>      In seiner Präsentation *zitierte* der Student Shakespeare.
>      [He actually used Shakespeare’s words.]

Comment: Frage gerettet und gut beantwortet!

Answer (score 3):

You can only quote some**one**, while you can cite some**one** or some**thing**.

German speakers don't make a difference, it's both either *zitieren* (to cite/to quote) or *wiedergeben* (to quote/to cite).

> Jürgen gab bloß Thomas wieder.

*Jürgen just quoted Thomas.*

> Jürgen gab bloß wieder, was auf dem Schild stand.

*Jürgen just cited what was written on the sign.*

Comment: The *main difference* requires *a knowledge of another language than German* and is off-topic here. I expect Aaron to have this knowledge, and his question being about the —to English speakers— puzzling fact German does not make this difference.

Comment: Na ja, mir stellt sich da noch die Frage, worin genau der Unterschied zwischen Zitieren und Rezitieren im Deutschen liegt. Das sollte hier mit rein.

Comment: Wer verwendet überhaupt je das Verb *rezitieren*?

Comment: @Janka: Gedicht aufsagen = rezitieren ... wäre meine Verwendung von rezitieren. Ansonsten fehlt mir in der Frage, worin der Unterschied von quote und cite im Englischen besteht, Philipp hat einen Hinweis "kommentiert".

Comment: Ich würde hingegen einfach ein Gedicht aufsagen.

Comment: Soweit ich https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rezitation verstehe, ist rezitieren eine Wiedergabe mit eigener Interpration durch Intonation & Darstellung - geht also im schriftlichen quasi nicht, da das dort fehlt.